# how to extract the last id from URL

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a column of urls where I want to extract the last element of each url which represent and ID I am looking for.

I managed to use 'basename' to extract all the text after the last slash.
Here is an example of the url that that I extracted

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukgCE.png)

I want to extract that last number. I used this script but it seems that I am extract just the first one and copying it in other rows.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df = read.csv('~/Downloads/urls.csv')

df = df %>%
  mutate(temp = str_split(string = url,pattern = '-')) %>%
  mutate(id = temp[[1]][length(temp[[1]])])
```

I used the code above and I am expecting to get an id variable with these values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66MMO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this column in a dataframe

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  url                                  
  <chr>                                
1 essential-back-pain-stretches-3120312
2 what-is-myotome-296992
```

Extracting IDs with regex

```
df %>% 
  mutate(id = str_extract(url, pattern = "([^-]+)$"))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  url                                   id     
  <chr>                                 <chr>  
1 essential-back-pain-stretches-3120312 3120312
2 what-is-myotome-296992                296992
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tom. That was awesome. can you recommand a book where I can learn regex? Thanks